# Victorian English slang: 'earnest' ~ 'gay'?

Tags: meaning, slang

Is it true that Victorians would understand earnest in a slang sense to mean gay? For example, in Wilde's The Importance of Being Earnest is there an assumed pun on "earnest"? This was suggested in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Importance_of_Being_Earnest#Suggested_homosexual_subtext):

> The use of the name Earnest may have been a homosexual in-joke. In 1892, three years before Wilde wrote the play, John Gambril Nicholson had published the book of pederastic poetry *Love in Earnest*. The sonnet *Of Boys' Names* included the verse: "Though Frank may ring like silver bell / And Cecil softer music claim / They cannot work the miracle / –'Tis Ernest sets my heart a-flame."<sup>[76]</sup> The word "earnest" may also have been a code-word for homosexual, as in: "Is he earnest?", in the same way that "Is he so?" and "Is he musical?" were employed.<sup>[77]</sup>
>
> ---
>
> [76] Nicholson (1892:61) (*Love in Earnest: Sonnets, Ballades, and Lyrics*)
>    [77] Ellmann (1988:88) (*a long the riverrun: Selected Essays*)

Comment: Where did you first hear the idea that 'earnest' used to mean what is currently meant by 'gay'?

Comment: " In Victorian times earnestness was considered to be the over-riding societal value, originating in religious attempts to reform the lower classes, it spread to the upper ones too throughout the century."  And..."The word "earnest" may also have been a code-word for homosexual,"  AND...Earnest was the name the 2 sisters considered to be a good name to marry.-Wikipedia

Comment: As an aside, the most obvious pun in that play is that one of the characters is named 'Earnest' who had unwittingly been using a different name but was born with that name and then the engagement depending on what name he had and Banburying down to London and Lady Bracknell and cucumber sandwiches and suffice it to say he got the girl by being sincere, haha his name means 'sincere'. Get it? Earnest needed to be earnest. It's funny because Rupert Everett is a happy guy.

Comment: @Cascabel Oh. Wikipedia. People will conjecture anything. And then add it to Wikipedia.

Comment: All the references to this that I can find are prefixed with “maybe” or “some say that” and similar caveats. I’m not convinced that it isn’t a retrospective invention.

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, which is why I just about never use it in an answer...but it can be a good place to start _research_.

Comment: @Cascabel Like Urban Dictionary. But Wikipedia seems so _factual_.

Comment: At least Wikipedia (usually) provides references to sources. I’m not sure I have ever seen that on Urban Dict, which is more useful as a source of what I believe the young people call “lols”.

Comment: Consider that "nice" or "sweet" or any number of other terms might be said, with a certain tone of voice, to convey the implication of homosexuality.

Comment: @Cascabel I can't find that quote on the wiki page. Can you give a link to where you found it?

Comment: @Mitch scroll down to ["A satire on society"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Importance_of_Being_Earnest)

Comment: @Cascabel Now that there is more context about it, this is actually an interesting historical question. It'll be difficult to prove either way that it is beyond the ineffectual but what most people think 'That sounds crazy'/'That sounds just like Wilde'.

Comment: @Mitch you cannot [compare Urban Dictionary to Wikipedia](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/458096/victorian-english-slang-earnest-gay#comment1103175_458096), you're really doing the latter a disservice. Maybe ten years ago Wiki entries were not properly supported, and it was easier to deface. But nowadays, most of what I read on Wikipedia, is a compendium of different sources. It's rare to come across something "original" and "groundbreaking". We leave that to authors and scientists who publish their original work. Then if it finds some consensus it makes its way to wiki.

Comment: @Mari-LouA To be pedantic, there _is_ a comparison, and Wikipedia comes out better. They at least have standards and moderation (which may even be onerous at times). The expectation is different: one expects that _eventually_ WP will self-correct. But still, anyone can edit to put something in, conjectural and without reference, like the case in point that motivated this ELU question.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true that Victorians would understand earnest in a slang sense to mean gay?

Very doubtful.

Is it true that Victorians who were active in the underground queer scene of the time would have understood it that way?

Less doubtful, but still pretty doubtful.

It's been suggested that Earnest and indeed Cecil (the name of another character in the play is the related Cecily) were used as slang within the queer scene of the time. *Earnest* in particular allows for a crude pun; we talk about being "in earnest" which allows one to ask "Earnest who?" punning that "in earnest" means sexually penetrating a man called Earnest. By extension *Earnest* **could** become a slang term for a gay or otherwise queer man, particularly one who enjoyed bottoming for penetrative sex.

This is conjectural though. I haven't read the article cited as suggesting this (Laurence Senelick, "Master Wood's Profession: Wilde and the Subculture of Homosexual Blackmail in the Victorian Theatre", in *Wilde Writings: Contextual Conditions*) but some who have cited it seem sceptical of it. Neither *Earnest*, *Cecil*, nor *Cecily* appear in any of the lexicons of Polari (the gay and theatre cant in London from the Victorian times through to the middle of the 20th century) I've seen as far as I recall, nor in any I can find online with an (admittedly not very thorough) search.

But then, there were certainly subtleties to how queer slang could work. "Is he so?" as you quote above certainly was used to mean "is he queer?" but is also says very little to those not in the know. While Polari and its relatives stand out as being blatantly unusual speech, though the meaning may not be penetrable to the aunt nells of most naff omis (ears of most straight men), subtler communications were important too.

To say that *Earnest* "may" have been understood that way, which is all the quote claims, seems reasonable enough. To go beyond "may" seems a stretch.

A big caveat to this is that a lot of readings trying to find signposts of homosexual activity in Wilde's works began with his libel suit (which in turn led to his criminal trial) and continued ever since. Some such suggestions are almost certainly wrong (e.g. suggestions of the word *bun* elsewhere referring to buttocks are anachronistic and of their referring to queer brothels seem fully unsupported). The existence of more doubtful signals found in his work leads one to suspicion of all attempts to find them. While Wilde is certainly open to queer readings, I think most need to go at least a little further below the surface than just noting which names were used.

So, I'd go with the "may", but a very doubtful "may".

Comment: Yes, I suggest everyone read Umberto Eco's The Limits of Interpretation. "Umberto Eco focuses here on what he once called "the cancer of uncontrolled interpretation"—that is, the belief that many interpreters have gone too far in their domination of texts, thereby destroying meaning and the basis for communication." Indiana University Press

Comment: @Lambie oh, that takes me back! Yes, it's excellent, though I think the tendency to go the other way is almost as bad. The trick I think is to try to maintain an honest assessment of how far out on a limb one is going.

Comment: I call it backward over-reading or backward projection.  There will never be another Umberto Eco. [sigh] :)

Comment: @Lambie There will be something else. As soon as you think everything has already been said and said well, someone new says something new.

Comment: @Mitch I am agreeing with this answer.  There is no definitive proof that earnest was code for gay in The Importance of Being Earnest....